# Python - Cannot feed value of shape (64, 25, 9) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 25, 25)'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, signal-processing, placeholder

i am trying to train my RNN-LSTM model in python 3.5, this is my code and my dataset is a 3D accelerometer dataset

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, config.n_steps, config.n_inputs])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, config.n_classes])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        cost_history = np.empty(shape=[0],dtype=float)
        for b in range(total_batches):
            offset = (b * config.batch_size) % (train_y.shape[0] - config.batch_size)
            batch_x = train_x[offset:(offset + config.batch_size), :, :]
            batch_y = train_y[offset:(offset + config.batch_size), :]

            print ("batch_x shape =",batch_x.shape)
            print ("batch_y shape =",batch_y.shape)

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})
            cost_history = np.append(cost_history,c)
        loss_over_time[epoch] = np.mean(cost_history)
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Deep-Learning-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-master\ModelCreation\RNN\FFLSTM\fflstm.py", line 250, in <module>
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 25, 9) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 25, 25)'
```

and this is the shapes of my dataset

```
n_inputs len(X_train[0][0]) 25
batch_x shape = (64, 25, 9)
batch_y shape = (64, 2)
X <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 25, 25) dtype=float32>
Y <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `batch_x`'s shape (64, 25, 9) does not match the model expects (?, 25, 25).

You should either change `batch_x`'s shape to (64, 25, 25), or modify the `X` placeholder to become (?, 25, 9)

Comment: how to modify the X placeholder ?

Comment: Set `config.n_inputs` to 9 so it becomes `[None, config.n_steps, 9]`. Basically the batch shape has to match the input `X` shape.

Comment: @HadeerEl-Zayat Does this fix your problem?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: i tried to change the batch_x shape to (64,25,25) but it doesn't work